# Did I get these trigonometric functions correct?

Tags: trigonometry

Ok so I came across another question. Once again it says let $\cot\theta= 4/3$, with $\cos\theta<0$. Find the remaining trigonometric functions.

By using the identities I got:

\begin{align}
\sin\theta&=-3/5 \\
\cos\theta&=-4/5 \\
\tan\theta&=3/4  \\
\csc\theta&=-5/3 \\
\sec\theta&=-5/4
\end{align}

Comment: Well, to me your answers are correct. In here, $(x,y)=(-4,-3)$ and $\theta$ is in the $III$-quadrant.

Comment: $\cos \theta < 0$ what it means? And also its possible quadrant can be I.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh In the problem it's given that $\cos \theta<0.$ That means possible quadrants II,III. [then since tangent positive it's quad III].

Comment: Kanwaljit Singh it isn't possible for the quadrant to be 1 because cos theta < 0 thus it is a negative number and it is only negative im the 2nd a third quadrants but cot is only positive in the 1st and 3rd which is why it is indeed the 3rd quadrant

Comment: Ok I have only doubt in that.

Comment: Then your answer is correct.